# FFmeg_kt FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = 'Directory: '' (OS Error: Read-only file system, errno = 30)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using ffmpeg_kit to cut a video into 30-second pieces. First, I create a folder with a timestamp, and then I put the segmented video parts (each lasting 30 seconds) inside that folder. The code seems to be working fine on Android, but on iOS, I'm getting an error when I try to use this method.

```
  Future<void> splitVideo() async {
    try {
      Directory baseDirectory = Directory('${(await getApplicationSupportDirectory()).path}/trim/split/');
      //final String baseDirectory = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/trim/split/';

      final String timestamp = DateFormat('EEE-d-MMM-h:mm:ss:a').format(
        DateTime.now(),
      );
      final String formattedTimestamp =
      timestamp.replaceAll(':', '-').replaceAll(' ', '');
      final String outputDirectory = '$baseDirectory$formattedTimestamp/';
      final String fileNameBase = 'part_';

      // Create the directory
      Directory(outputDirectory).createSync(recursive: true);
      final String inputPath = widget.file.path;
      final Duration start = _controller.startTrim;
      final Duration end = _controller.endTrim;
      int partIndex = 1;
      Duration currentStart = start;

      while (currentStart < end) {
        final String outputFileName = '$fileNameBase$partIndex.mp4';
        final String outputPath = '$outputDirectory$outputFileName';

        // Calculate the end time for each part, ensuring it doesn't exceed the total video duration
        final Duration currentEnd = currentStart + const Duration(seconds: 30);
        final Duration actualEnd = currentEnd < end ? currentEnd : end;

        final String command =
            '-ss ${formatter(currentStart)} -t ${formatter(actualEnd - currentStart)} ' +
                '-i "$inputPath" ' +
                '-c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset ultrafast -b:v 500k -vf "scale=640:-2" ' +
                '-c:a aac -b:a 128k -strict experimental ' +
                '-avoid_negative_ts 1 "$outputPath"';

        int partDuration = (actualEnd - currentStart).inMilliseconds;
        int partProgress = 0;

        await FFmpegKit.executeAsync(command, (session) async {
          print('The command is executed: $command');
          final returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();

          if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(returnCode)) {
            print('Working fine, Return Code: $returnCode');
            progressNotifier.value = 100;
          } else {
            print('Error executing command. Return Code: $returnCode');
          }
        }, (Log log) {
          print('FFmpeg Log: ${log.getMessage()}');
        }, (Statistics statistics) {
          if (statistics == null) {
            return;
          }
          if (statistics.getTime() > 0) {
            partProgress = (statistics.getTime() * 100) ~/ partDuration;

            // Ensure progress doesn't exceed 100%
            if (partProgress > 100) {
              partProgress = 100;
            }

            print('Progress for part $partIndex: $partProgress%');

            progressNotifier.value = partProgress;
          }
        });
        MediaScanner.loadMedia(path: outputDirectory);

        print('Execution completed successfully for part $partIndex');

        // Update for the next part
        partIndex++;
        currentStart = actualEnd;
      }

      setState(() {});
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error splitting and limiting video size: $e');
    }
  }
```

flutter: Error splitting and limiting video size: FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = 'Directory: '' (OS Error: Read-only file system, errno = 30)